# Python Tkinter Layout Problems

Tags: python, layout, grid, tkinter, frame

I'm trying to use .grid() to make a tkinter layout. I have all my buttons aligned on the left side, and I want to put a textbox on the right. The problem is that when I try to do that, it messes up the buttons on the left. I've tried to use multiple frames but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the most important things to know about the grid geometry manager is the `columnspan` and `rowspan` keywords:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
buttons = [tk.Button(root,text=str(i)) for i in range(6)]
for i,b in enumerate(buttons):
    b.grid(row=i,column=0)

textbox = tk.Text(root)
textbox.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=6)

root.mainloop()
```

Note that a typical usage here is to use a `Frame` gridded with the correct `columnspan` and `rowspan`.  Then you can use that to manage the data.  An alternative to what I have above would be to use a `Frame` to hold all of the buttons and then grid the `Text` widget right next to it:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
buttons = [tk.Button(frame,text=str(i)) for i in range(6)]
for i,b in enumerate(buttons):
    b.grid(row=i,column=0)

textbox = tk.Text(root)
textbox.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the grid geometry manager, it is not necessary to use Frames for a 2-column layout. You can use `rowspan` to adjust the height of the Text widget to the number of buttons:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
N = 5

for i in range(N):
    Button(root, text="Button %s" % i).grid(row=i, column=0, padx=5)
Text(root, width=30).grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=N, padx=5)

root.mainloop()
```